# How to align everything in one line using CSS

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I want to align the contents / below mentioned links in one single straight line. I have entered them in my drupal 7 website. Any CSS help . I am unable to figure out.

[image: single straight line]

Comment: You need to show us what you have done so far, and what you have tried. We can't just make it for you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  try floating it to the left or display them as inline block elements

Answer (score 0):

Give li elements `float:left or inline-block` should work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Looking for</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Blogs</li>
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>Support</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I used a table and i entered the contents in a table row.